# diff a working copy with a previous revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out the latest revision (revision 5 for example) of a trunk from a local repository. I made some changes and now the working copy differs from revision 5 (latest). I want to diff my working copy with revision 2 before committing it. How do I use the command line or tortoise to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. right click on file
2. select tortoiseSvn menu and select Show Log
3. select revision 2 and right click on it
4. from sub menu select "compare with working copy"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the revision number at the command line. The call is like this:

```
svn diff -r N[:M]
```

where `M` default to your copy if omitted. So in your example you would do:

```
svn diff -r2
```